# Can I use pandoc to convert from markdown to DOCX or ODT and apply a template?

Tags: pandoc

I'm trying to use Pandoc to convert a markdown file into a Word (docx) or LibreOffice (odt) file, what is a simple thing to do...

But I want this converted ODT document to use a specific "OTT" LibreOffice template applied, using the defined styles and format. Is that possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, did you attempt anything? E.g. `pandoc input.md -f markdown --reference-doc ref.ott -o output.odt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as of pandoc 3.1.2 (the current version). Docx is a very complex format: important info is spread across multiple files that are interlinked and then compressed into a single zip file. It is not well suited for the templating method otherwise used by pandoc. The `--reference-doc` option can be used to customize the output, but it is limited.

See, e.g., this issue for more details: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3109